# what "android: inputType" to choose?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to enter only the following characters `0-9` and `_`

What "android: inputType" in EditText  to choose?

Comment: See what fits you via and handle invalid inputs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html
Or create you're own:
http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this in `XML`

```
android:digits="0123456789_"
```

Comment: @MaxUsanin cant help it as you need number + character

Comment: @MaxUsanin i think my answer fulfills your question

Answer (score 0):

Try and add this to your `EditText`

```
EditText text = findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text); /* Find your EditText here. */
text.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789_"));
```

Comment: not work, in the method onCreate EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fragment_authorization_1_edit_login);
    login.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789_"));

Comment: @MaxUsanin you r right. It's doesn't work.

public static DigitsKeyListener getInstance (String accepted) 
Returns a DigitsKeyListener that accepts only the characters that appear in the specified String. Note that not all characters may be available on every keyboard.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter only number then choose this `android:digits="0123456789_"`.

Answer (score 0):

ok.try the following code

```
   InputFilter[] Textfilters = new InputFilter[1];
    Textfilters[0] = new InputFilter(){
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (end > start) {

            char[] acceptedChars = new char[]{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '_'};

            for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {
                if (!new String(acceptedChars).contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(index)))) {
                return "";
                  }
                }
             }
                return null;
        }

    };
 editxt.setFilters(Textfilters);
```